# Show portion of UIImage in UIImageVIew

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

This question might have been answered, but I can't find a solution to my problem after hours of googling.

I have a `UIImageView` (320*320) in a **custom UITableCell** with a `UIImage` (320*320) inside.
When I click on a button, the `UIImageView` resizes to 320*80 (**animated**) and the UIImage too.

How could I do to prevent the `UIImage` from resizing ?
I would like this `UIImage` to stay but same and show only a portion of this image ( a 320*80 frame with 0/0 origin)

**Edit : Cropping**

I thought of cropping the image to the right size and then set the **UIImageView's** image to the fullsize image, but it looks ugly because when the user clicks on the **UIImageView**, this one is still 320*320 but the **UIImage** has been set to the cropped one (320*80) so it is streched...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing something similar in one of my apps, when I create the `UIImageView` object, I set the property `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, and the `clipsToBounds` property to `YES`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, you're a life saver, I started to do it with scrollview but I had just more problems. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can resize the image and then replace the UIImageView image with the resized one.

```
CGImageRef imageToBeResized = yourImage.CGImage;
CGImageRef partOfImageAsCG = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageToBeResized, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80));
CGRelease(imageToBeResized);
UIImage *resizedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageToBeResized];
```

Comment: I tried your solution and this is not exaclty what I want (see edited question)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should think about use a UIScrollView with your UIImageView inside. So, you can with  its properties to archive the desired behaviour.